# Is it possible to implement Comet chat with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, cometchat

I am currently working on x application the account has part of messaging which I have running so far and integrates with a website but there is a point where I need to make call and video call from the app but I stop so I need certain elements with the app, after the call is initialized, the following function must be called

```
CometChat.startCall(
 sessionID,
 document.getElementById("callScreen"),
 new CometChat.OngoingCallListener({
  onUserJoined: user => {
   /* Notification received here if another user joins the call. */
   console.log("User joined call:", user);
   /* this method can be use to display message or perform any actions if someone joining the call */
  },
  onUserLeft: user => {
   /* Notification received here if another user left the call. */
   console.log("User left call:", user);
   /* this method can be use to display message or perform any actions if someone leaving the call */
  },
  onCallEnded: call => {
   /* Notification received here if current ongoing call is ended. */
   console.log("Call ended:", call);
   /* hiding/closing the call screen can be done here. */
  }
 })
);
```

and I got to the point of ... I think this cannot be applied since it receives as a parameter a `document.getElementById ('root')`
Some experience confirming whether this technology can be used in react native. This is to the documentation of the liberia.

https://prodocs.cometchat.com/docs/js-quick-start

I am using react native 0.65 and @cometchat-pro/react-native-chat

Comment: Video calling is available in 2.1. Check:  https://prodocs.cometchat.com/v2.1/docs/react-native-calling

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the information, as I see that version was added recently because it did not have that functionality when I wanted to use it, it is a great shame because I had to move to https://connectycube.com and This solved my problem.